# Nilpotent matrices over a ring

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Any suggestions or ideas what method can be used to count the number of $2 \times 2$ nilpotent matrices over a ring $\mathbb{Z}_p [i]$ which is a prime field.

Comment: See https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255454112 . Fine and Herstein prove that the number of $n\times n$ nilpotent matrices over a finite field of order $q$ is $q^{n^2-n}$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nilpotent matrices over finite fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69962/nilpotent-matrices-over-finite-fields)

Answer (score 1):

The nonzero nilpotent $2\times 2$ matrices are the conjugates of $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$. The matrices commuting with $A$ are those
of the form $rI+sA$, and there are $q(q-1)$ of these which are invertible
when we are working over the finite field of order $q$. So $A$
has $|\textrm{GL}_2(q)|/(q(q-1))=q^2-1$ conjugates, so overall there are
$q^2$ nilpotent matrices.

Comment: What is $r$ and $s$ ?