# p-nilpotent matrices in characteristic p

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, matrix-equations

Let $p$ be a prime, $\mathbb{F}_p$ the field of $p$ elements. Is it possible to describe $n \times n$ (for $n$ sufficiently large if needed) matrices $M$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ such that $M^p = 0$? Does the exponent of $p$ have more consequences than just saying that $M$ is nilpotent?

What if we look at a prime power $q$ and matrices over $\mathbb{F}_q$: can we describe matrices $M$ such that $M^p = 0$? Or such that $M^q = 0$?

**Edit** Any nilpotent matrix $M$ will satisfy $M^n = 0$, as pointed out in the comments. I am hoping for some stronger consequence that apply specifically to matrices that are $p$-nilpotent. Ideally some result of the form "any such matrix is conjugate to something of this form".

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "describe"? How about [this description](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69962/nilpotent-matrices-over-finite-fields)?

Comment: Surely (in $M^p=0$ case) $M$ is similar to $\bigoplus_{r=1}^{p} k_r J_r(0)$ with $\sum_{r=1}^{p} k_r r=n$.